# The kernel function corresponding to a quadratic form rather than inner product

Tags: reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

We all know that for a feature map $\Phi$, there exists a kernel function $K_1$ satisfying  $\langle\Phi (x),\Phi (y)\rangle=K_1(x,y)$. 
For a positive-deﬁnite matrix $A$, the quadratic form $\langle\Phi (x),A\Phi (y)\rangle=\langle A^{1/2}\Phi (x),A^{1/2}\Phi (y)\rangle$, so there also exists a kernel function $K_2$ satisfying  $\langle\Phi (x),A\Phi (y)\rangle=K_2(x,y)$.

I want to know whether there is some relationship between $K_2$ and $K_1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is positive definite, by the properties of its eigenvalues (see [Rayleigh Quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient), for example), the values of the quadratic form are bounded. For any vector $v$ in the feature space, we have that:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_\min \langle v, v \rangle \leq \langle v, Av \rangle \leq \lambda_\max \langle v, v \rangle\,,
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_\min$ and $\lambda_\max$ denote the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $A$, respectively. Therefore, we can say that:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_\min K_1(x,x) \leq K_2(x,x) \leq \lambda_\max K_1(x,x)\,,
\end{equation}
for all $x$.